# How remove rows with same value in their relation but different ID in two columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a huge data set with repeated information in a variable when this relation is understood in sense ID1, ID2 or ID2, ID1 (those in different columns), also values in the variable can be repeated from different IDs relations. I want to delete same info with reverse ID order like this:

```
ID1         ID2         value
BHFUD13XG   KLSIENAL1   0.3475
GLADKK123   FBNAFLEL2   0.2956
KLSIENAL1   BHFUD13XG   0.3475
FBNAFLEL2   GLADKK123   0.2956
DGFEORM23   SHDKG14NV   0.3475
SHDKG14NV   DGFEORM23   0.3475
```

Clean

```
ID1         ID2         value
BHFUD13XG   KLSIENAL1   0.3475
GLADKK123   FBNAFLEL2   0.2956
DGFEORM23   SHDKG14NV   0.3475
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do not post your data with an image.

Comment: We can't copy/paste data from images. Please leave the useful edit as it was, with data in plain text format.

Comment: this somehow looks to me that there might be a data preparation step before which might be done differently and more efficiently. ?

Answer (score 6):

As you said, if data is huge, it's not a good idea to use `rowwise`, but you may try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(key = paste0(sort(c(ID1,ID2)), collapse = "-")) %>%
  select(value, key) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  separate(key, c("ID1", "ID2"), "-")

  value ID1       ID2      
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    
1 0.348 BHFUD13XG KLSIENAL1
2 0.296 FBNAFLEL2 GLADKK123
3 0.348 DGFEORM23 SHDKG14NV
```

or

```
df %>%
  mutate(id1 = pmin(ID1, ID2), id2 = pmax(ID1, ID2)) %>%
  select(id1, id2, value) %>%
  distinct()

        id1       id2  value
1 BHFUD13XG KLSIENAL1 0.3475
2 FBNAFLEL2 GLADKK123 0.2956
3 DGFEORM23 SHDKG14NV 0.3475
```

## add

```
df %>%
  mutate(id1 = pmin(ID1, ID2), id2 = pmax(ID1, ID2)) %>%
  distinct(id1, id2, value, .keep_all = T) %>%
  select(-id1, -id2) # and select whatever you want.

        ID1       ID2  value       id1       id2
1 BHFUD13XG KLSIENAL1 0.3475 BHFUD13XG KLSIENAL1
2 GLADKK123 FBNAFLEL2 0.2956 FBNAFLEL2 GLADKK123
3 DGFEORM23 SHDKG14NV 0.3475 DGFEORM23 SHDKG14NV
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! :) Is possible in the case that I want to keep additional columns information in my data, but delete the rows with the same logic (value, ID1, and ID2) as you propose?

Comment: @portillanath add `.keep_all = T` argument then select whatever you want in `select(...)` part. Add `-` in front of column name means remove that column.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

t <- tibble(
  ID1=c('BHFUD13XG','GLADKK123','KLSIENAL1','FBNAFLEL2','DGFEORM23','SHDKG14NV'),
  ID2=c('KLSIENAL1','FBNAFLEL2','BHFUD13XG','GLADKK123','SHDKG14NV','DGFEORM23'),
  value=c(.3475, .2956, .3475, .2956, .3475, .3475)
)

t
```

---

```
  ID1       ID2       value
  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
1 BHFUD13XG KLSIENAL1 0.3475
2 GLADKK123 FBNAFLEL2 0.2956
3 KLSIENAL1 BHFUD13XG 0.3475
4 FBNAFLEL2 GLADKK123 0.2956
5 DGFEORM23 SHDKG14NV 0.3475
6 SHDKG14NV DGFEORM23 0.3475
```

---

```
MakeKeys <- function(x) {
  # Replace `utf8ToInt` with appropriate encoding
  m <- map(x, function(s){sum(utf8ToInt(s))})
  flatten_int(m)
}

t <- t %>% mutate(k=MakeKeys(ID1)+MakeKeys(ID2)) %>% 
  distinct(k, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
  select(-k)

t
```

---

```
  ID1       ID2       value
  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
1 BHFUD13XG KLSIENAL1 0.3475
2 GLADKK123 FBNAFLEL2 0.2956
3 DGFEORM23 SHDKG14NV 0.3475
```